# How to vectorize this code to run without any for loops in Octave and how many?

Tags: octave, vectorization

Hi Can someone help me to vectorize this code in Octave

```
v = zeros(10, 1);
for i = 1:10
  for j = 1:10
    v(i) = v(i) + A(i, j) * x(j);
  end
end
```

Thank You!

Comment: A description of what it's doing might be nice. Are you just doing the elementwise multiplication of `A(i,:)` and `x` and then summing the rows?

Answer (score 1):

If size(x) = (10,1), then...

#### v = A * x;

Hope this helps!